# index, small, subtotal, returning multiple matches from filter cell

Tags: excel, indexing, row, subtotal

I have the following index/match lookup only in visible cell working properly, however....

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$F$500,SMALL(IF(((SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($G$2:$G$500,ROW($G$2:$G$500)-MIN(ROW($G$2:$G$500)),,1))>0)*($K$517=$G$2:$G$500)),ROW($G$2:$G$500)-MIN(ROW($G$2:$G$500))+1),1)),"")
```

Column F is what I want returning, Column G has the criteria value in them.  `K517` is the lookup value.

Now from Column F there are more then 1 results to be return.  I want to use the & and string all the return results in a single cell.  How should I approach?

To clarify, Say I want to look up "Adam" (`K517`) it returned the first value "red" from Column F.  However, there are also "yellow and Blue" that matches "Adam".  So I want in a cell to display (Red, yellow, blue) based on the filtered cell.  Hope that make sense, thank you in advance.

James,

Comment: vba will be your best bet, You can probably get there with TEXTJOIN if you have access to it.  If not then vba is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `TEXTJOIN` function available you can use this array formula to return all matches in one cell

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,INDEX($F$2:$F$500,N(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($G$2:$G$500,ROW($G$2:$G$500)-MIN(ROW($G$2:$G$500)),0,1)),IF($K$517=$G$2:$G$500,ROW($G$2:$G$500)-MIN(ROW($G$2:$G$500))+1)))))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

....or with this version you can get one result per cell e.g. in `K2` copied down until you get blanks

`=IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$F$500,SMALL(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($G$2:$G$500,ROW($G$2:$G$500)-MIN(ROW($G$2:$G$500)),0,1)),IF($K$517=$G$2:$G$500,ROW($G$2:$G$500)-MIN(ROW($G$2:$G$500))+1)),ROWS(K$2:K2))),"")`

also needs <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it this way but if you have to use a formula and you have a known maximum number of returned values you could concatenate the 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc. matches e.g. with 3 results (don't forget CTRL + SHFT + ENTER). The Err test makes sure you don't end up with extraneous commas.

```
=IF(IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$F500,MATCH($K$517,$G$2:$G500,0)),"Err") = "Err","", 
INDEX($F2:$F500,MATCH($K$517,$G$2:$G500,0))) & 
IF(IFERROR(INDEX($F2:$F500,SMALL(IF($G$2:$G500=$K$517,ROW($G$2:$G500)-
MIN(ROW($G$2:$G500))+2),2)),"Err")="Err","Err", ", " & 
INDEX($F2:$F500,SMALL(IF($G$2:$G500=$K$517,ROW($G$2:$G500)-
MIN(ROW($G$2:$G500))+2),2))) & 
IF(IFERROR(INDEX($F2:$F500,SMALL(IF($G$2:$G500=$K$517,ROW($G$2:$G500)-
MIN(ROW($G$2:$G500))+2),2)),"Err")="Err","", ", " & 
INDEX($F2:$F500,SMALL(IF($G$2:$G500=$K$517,ROW($G$2:$G500)-
MIN(ROW($G$2:$G500))+2),3)))
```